# Sum of Columns which Contain Differennt Data Type

Tags: sql

I am trying to sum the cost value but the problem I believe is in my cost column there are not set and null values beside actual values. So `Sum(t.cost)` gives me wrong sum and `coalesce(t.cost)` gives me the wrong sum. What needs to be done to get the right sum for each student?

Comment: Why would `sum(t.cost)` give you wrong values if some are NULL?  SQL ignores the NULL values when doing the sum.

Comment: Show us your query, sample data, and expected result.

Comment: Exactly, if you just do sum(t.cost), aggregation function will ignore the null. Must be something else wrong. You need to share some sample data.

Comment: would it ignore the value 'notset' and undefined as well from the column

Answer (score 0):

I presume that your "cost" column is not numeric ?!? Whatever...

```
declare @t table (id int, cost varchar(10) null)

insert into @t values (1,'123.456')
insert into @t values (2,'456.789')
insert into @t values (3,null)
insert into @t values (3,'notset')

select sum(cast(nullif(cost,'notset') as money)) from @t
```